# How to get pr_auc metric for both factor within tidymodels workflow?

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am running classification models for an outcome with 2 factors. The code below works correctly and has no errors. It gives the metric values for the the combination model-recipe I need for the factor `male`. How can I get the metric results for the female factor in the same time within `workflow_map`? I am able to save the prediction with `control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)` and calculate `pr_auc` for `.pred_female` and `.pred_male` after the fact but then I cannot find exactly the same results as with using `collect_metrics` directly. Any idea?

```r
# Import library
library(reprex)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(themis)

# Prep data
data(penguins)
penguins <- na.omit(penguins) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, factor)
str(penguins$sex)
#>  Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 ...

set.seed(1234)

# 1. Splitting the data
# 3/4 of the data into the training set but split evenly winthin race
data_split <- initial_split(penguins, prop = .75)
# Create training and testing datasets:
train_data <- training(data_split)
test_data  <- testing(data_split)


# Create recipe
recipe_basic <-
  recipe(sex ~ ., data = train_data)

recipe_norm <-
  recipe(sex ~ ., data = train_data)  %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())

recipe_list <-
  list(basic = recipe_basic,
       normalized = recipe_norm)

# Create model
dt_spec <- decision_tree(cost_complexity = tune(), tree_depth = tune(), min_n = tune()) %>%
  set_engine("rpart") %>%
  set_mode("classification")

ranger_spec <- rand_forest(
  mtry = tune(),
  min_n = tune(),
  trees = tune()) %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  set_engine("ranger")

model_list <-
  list(Random_Forest = ranger_spec,
       Decision_Tree = dt_spec)

model_set <- workflow_set(preproc = recipe_list, models = model_list, cross = T)

class_metric <- metric_set(roc_auc, pr_auc)

set.seed(1234)
mldata_folds <- vfold_cv(train_data)

doParallel::registerDoParallel()
set.seed(1234)
all_workflows <-
  model_set %>% workflow_map(resamples = mldata_folds, 
                             metrics = class_metric,
                             verbose = TRUE,
                             control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE))
#> i 1 of 4 tuning:     basic_Random_Forest
#> i Creating pre-processing data to finalize unknown parameter: mtry
#> ✔ 1 of 4 tuning:     basic_Random_Forest (4.4s)
#> i 2 of 4 tuning:     basic_Decision_Tree
#> ✔ 2 of 4 tuning:     basic_Decision_Tree (2.3s)
#> i 3 of 4 tuning:     normalized_Random_Forest
#> i Creating pre-processing data to finalize unknown parameter: mtry
#> ✔ 3 of 4 tuning:     normalized_Random_Forest (4.5s)
#> i 4 of 4 tuning:     normalized_Decision_Tree
#> ✔ 4 of 4 tuning:     normalized_Decision_Tree (2.4s)

# Get pr_auc metric
collect_metrics(all_workflows) %>%
  filter(.metric == "pr_auc") %>%
  group_by(wflow_id) %>%
  summarize(wfl_mean = mean(mean))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   wflow_id                 wfl_mean
#>   <chr>                       <dbl>
#> 1 basic_Decision_Tree         0.877
#> 2 basic_Random_Forest         0.966
#> 3 normalized_Decision_Tree    0.877
#> 4 normalized_Random_Forest    0.966

# Using collect_predictions for female - not same value
collect_predictions(all_workflows) %>% 
  group_by(wflow_id) %>%
  pr_auc(sex, .pred_female)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   wflow_id                 .metric .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>                    <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 basic_Decision_Tree      pr_auc  binary         0.870
#> 2 basic_Random_Forest      pr_auc  binary         0.960
#> 3 normalized_Decision_Tree pr_auc  binary         0.870
#> 4 normalized_Random_Forest pr_auc  binary         0.960

# Using collect_predictions for female and summarize = FALSE - not same value
collect_predictions(all_workflows, summarize = FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(wflow_id, id) %>%
  pr_auc(sex, .pred_female) %>% 
  group_by(wflow_id) %>%
  summarize(mean_prauc = mean(.estimate))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   wflow_id                 mean_prauc
#>   <chr>                         <dbl>
#> 1 basic_Decision_Tree           0.867
#> 2 basic_Random_Forest           0.965
#> 3 normalized_Decision_Tree      0.867
#> 4 normalized_Random_Forest      0.965

# Using collect_predictions for male
collect_predictions(all_workflows) %>% 
  group_by(wflow_id) %>%
  pr_auc(sex, .pred_male)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   wflow_id                 .metric .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>                    <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 basic_Decision_Tree      pr_auc  binary         0.326
#> 2 basic_Random_Forest      pr_auc  binary         0.309
#> 3 normalized_Decision_Tree pr_auc  binary         0.326
#> 4 normalized_Random_Forest pr_auc  binary         0.309
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure this makes statistical sense?

Comment: Yes https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html. I need to report both in papers. It can be done easily outside worklow_map when fitting the last model but I want these values before in order to pick the best model-recipe to choose.

Comment: Auc for discrete unordered variables?

Comment: Sex is a categorical variable